# How to run different javascript files on different URLs in a single chrome extension

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I know if I want to run a javascript or multiple javascript files on a single url you use this format in the manifest.json.

```
"content_scripts": [
 {
  "matches": [
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "js": ["content.js"]
 }
]
```

However I would like to know how to run a single javascript file on example.com/test and a totally different javascript file on example.com/shop. Is this possible or would this be accomplished with example.com/* in the manifest.json and have some line in the script checking `if url contains 'shop'` or something like that?

Comment: Have you check to add a router in your application?

Comment: @floverdevel no, I have no clue what your talking about 'add a router' could you explain, Thanks

Comment: could you conditionally do logic in your script files based on the url?

Comment: From my experience the approach you're outlining is the way you have to go. I was not able to filter on individual URL paths and instead had to match the domain (example.com/*) and then do the 'url contains "shop"' logic in the js. It may not be the most elegant approach but it works.

Comment: @DanielA.White Thats what I was thinking I had to do, `if (window.location.href.indexOf('shop') != -1)` would something like this work, or do you have a better example.

Comment: See the documentation for content scripts: you can use "matches" key to restrict content scripts to an URL pattern, and you can define multiple "content_scripts" entries with different patterns and js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation for [content_scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

Example partial `manifest.json`:

```
...
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "run_at": "document_end",
    "matches": [
      "https://*.stackexchange.com/*"
    ],
    "js": [
      "vendor.bundle.js",
      "stackexchange.js"
    ],
    "css": []
  },
  {
    "run_at": "document_start",
    "matches": [
      "https://*.stackoverflow.com/*"        ],
    "js": [
      "vendor.bundle.js",
      "stackoverflow.js"
    ],
    "css": []
  }
],
...
```